# Errors not showing up in blade file in laravel5.5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.5

I am applying validation on form. I am receiving error messages in json but, errors are not showing up in blade file.

Following is the code, i have written in controller file for validation:-

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\SpecialOffers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Validator;

use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class SpecialoffersController extends Controller
{

 /**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function NewPromotion()
{
    return view('new-promotion');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

   // Validate and store the values....
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'promotion_name' => 'required',
        'service' => 'required',
        'promotion' => 'required',
        'promotion_details' => 'required',

    ]);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        // Get the currently authenticated user...
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
    $id = Auth::id();

    $promotion_name = $_POST['promotion_name'];
    $service = $_POST['service'];
    $promotion = $_POST['promotion'];
    $promotion_details = $_POST['promotion_details'];

    $insert = DB::insert('insert into special_offers_details(user_id,promotion_name,service,promotion_limited,promotion_details,price,sent_to) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['',$promotion_name, $service, $promotion, $promotion_details,'','']);

    $result = array();

    if($insert==1)
    {
        $result['message']='Successfully inserted';
        $result['html']='1';
    }
    else
    {
        $result['message']='error';
        $result['html']='0';
    }

    //echo json_encode($result);
    return json_encode($result);
    }

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
        //return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
    }

}
```

}
The errors are displaying up response but not showing up in view file. Following code is the code in view file for calling errors:-

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

I am not getting that why errors are not showing up. What is missing?

Comment: have you tried dumping the `$errors`?

Comment: the store function returns json not a view

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning it in JSON format this will not be rendered by the blade template since php cannot read  JSON directly what you do just return error response in a php array format